# In subclassing ArrayAdapter the view coming through to the getView is null? Why?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm subclassing ArrayAdapter, but the view coming through to the getView is null? Why is that?

I'm having to specify the view manually in the getView method. Where does the view come from that is sent to this method?

```
public class CustomList2 extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public CustomList2(Context context, int layout_id, ArrayList<String> objects){
        super(context, layout_id, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup view_group) {
       if(view == null) 
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
           view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
       }
      return view;
    }
}
```

The adapter and view are set like this:

```
video_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
video_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View sent to getView might be null when there are no views to be reused.

If it is null, you need to create your View or call super (like ianhanniballake suggested).

This is a cache functionality inside ListView, which makes it a bit more responsive.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to call the super class' `getView` method to get the default behavior:

```
public class CustomList2 extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public CustomList2(Context context, int layout_id, ArrayList<String> objects){
        super(context, layout_id, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup view_group) {
        view = super.getView(position, view, view_group);
        // Do something special with the view
        return view;
    }
}
```